# iOS time-sensitive notifications cannot break through Focus mode

Tags: ios, swift, iphone, swiftui

I am trying to implement time-sensitive local notifications for my iOS app. The app sends a local notification at the set time interval.

For some reason, the notifications cannot break through Focus mode and are delivered silently.

- I ask for notification permissions at the app's start like below.

```
    _ = try? await notificationScheduler.requestAuthorization(options: [.alert, .badge, .sound, .provisional])
    // Using UNUserNotificationCenter.current under the hood
```

- I have added the Time-Sensitive Notification Capability to my app. And it's enabled in the entitlements as expected.

[image: capabilities]
[image: entitlements]

- I am setting my local notifications as below:

```
    let content = UNMutableNotificationContent()
    content.title = Self.wakeUpAlarmTitle
    content.interruptionLevel = .timeSensitive
    content.sound = UNNotificationSound.default
    let trigger = UNTimeIntervalNotificationTrigger(timeInterval: calculateTimeInterval()),repeats: false)
                
    let request = UNNotificationRequest(identifier: UUID().uuidString,
                                        content: content,
                                        trigger: trigger)
                
    notificationScheduler.add(request, withCompletionHandler: nil)
```

- My app's time-sensitive notifications are correctly enabled in the settings app.
  [image: notification permissions]

After this setup, my notifications are still delivered silently if the device is in Focus mode like Do Not Disturb or Sleep.

My understanding is that time-sensitive notifications should break through Focus mode and play sound and be delivered immediately.

Am I missing a configuration step, or time-sensitive notifications does not work anymore?

Thanks